# Cancel SqlDataSource selecting rows when SelectCommand timeout

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource, selectcommand

How can I cancel selecting rows in `SqlDataSource` when `SelectCommand`timed out?
I know that I can set `CommandTimeout` property but I want to Handle error and force Page to continue running when `SqlDataSource` timed out.

for more information:
in my page, a `ListView` use `SqlDataSource` result but this result is not my main content and just recommendation similar list for main content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: after `Selecting` timed out, `SqlDataSource` `Selected` event start running.

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Selected
    If e.Exception is nothing=false andalso e.Exception.InnerException.ToString.ToLower.Contains("timed out") Then
        ListView1.Visible = False
        e.ExceptionHandled = True
    End If
End Sub
```